# Securing gsp files

Tags: grails, spring-security, security, gsp

I'm relatively new to Spring, but very new to Spring Security and Grails.  To be brief, I know its recommended to not allow .jsp files to be servable, you should toss them in WEB-INF, and set up your controllers to pull them from the right place.

How would I go about doing this in Grails?  It seems that I would destroy the idea of "convention over configuration" by tossing gsp's into WEB-INF and then writing logic into all my controllers (if that's even immediately possible...)  It seems I would have to alter some basic Grails configurations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I haven't seen a complete answer for this here (or elsewhere one StackOverflow) that provides a full valid result, so here's what I've come up with:

First, create a new controller:

```
grails create-controller gspForbidden
```

Open this up, and add this to the index action:

```
index = {
    response.status = 404
}
```

Then, open `grails-app/conf/UrlMappings.groovy` and add this under the `static mappings` closure:

```
"/grails-app/**.gsp"(controller:"gspForbidden")
```

This will redirect *any* attempts to view a GSP directly to the `gspForbidden` controller.  That controller, in turn, simply renders a 404 - a file not found response.  The best thing about this is that it's completely hidden - there's nothing showing that the GS path was correct, so there's less chance of exposing something important about the application design.

I tried repeatedly to figure out how to use `UrlMappings` to show a 404 without the controller, but I had no success.  If you can think of a way, please let me know.  I'd much rather have this happen without any explicit controllers.

Comment: For now I'll follow your suggestion.  Is there a specific reason you want to stay away from a controller?  If you configure spring-security properly, you shouldn't have to worry terribly much about http-method-protection...  In the meantime, when I get downtime I'll try to find a way to improve on this as you suggested.

Comment: Only for cleanliness.  It seems silly to have an entire class and controller just to throw a 404 error.  :-)  I finally traced the UrlMappings classes (there's something like 10 of them) to figure out how it's working, and I don't think it's possible without the controller.  It's not a big issue.

Answer (score 2):

Slight correction to earlier post:

Just adhering to the convention in Grails doesn't prevent someone who guesses where a gsp lives from hitting it directly (I just tried it, it works).

Comment: And for those who want to try, just go to any deployed grails app, and browse to: `<context>/grails-app/views/<controller>/<view>.gsp`.  Yikes!  Seems like this is a pretty major security hole.

Comment: Thanks for verifying this... I'm taking the GSSP-J class right now and my work has me learning Grails.  This part of the course made alarm bells ring... thanks for your work, Bill and OverZealous!

Answer (score 1):

From Spring Security Plugin Documentation:

```
package com.testapp
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class SecureController {

   @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
   def index = {
      render 'Secure access only'
   }
}
```

you can secure your GSP pages as the example above. Secured annotation will provide access only to a user if they have the admin rights.

for more information , refer to :

http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/

tutorials are nice as a start.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to worry about this in Grails. If you follow the conventions of using views and controllers it will handle all the details about making sure the GSP pages aren't directly accessible.

As far as integration with Spring Security is concerned, again if you follow one of the recommended patterns (URL security or annotation within your controllers) you should be fine.